# Complex Pages and Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle pages in our application like the dashboard, where there are a number of different panes with various bits of data in it.

The main issue is that the controller action becomes unwieldy when the page needs so much data. The client side can be broken up into partial views to make it more manageable, but all the data still needs to passed into the View to be distributed down to the partials. Or does it?

Obviously some of the panels could be loaded dynamically or something like that, but I was looking for the best approach besides loading individual piece of the page from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `Html.Action` in your view?  You would pass enough data to the main view to enable you to give the required data to each of the child actions. The main action would render the main view which would call actions for each pane. Each action would be responsible for that pane, rendering its own partial view. Additionally, you could call back to each of the child actions directly from the client to update that pane dynamically via AJAX.

Here's an example with some mocked up actions of what your main view might look like.

```
 <div class="left-pane">
    @Html.Action("Summary", new { id = Model.ID } )
 </div>
 <div class="middle-pane">
    @Html.Action("PendingItems", new { id = Model.ID, timestamp = DateTime.Now } )
 </div>
 <div class="right-pane">
    @Html.Action("News")
 </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't figure out the right search terms to find it.